# Summarise Variable in stable period

Tags: r, tidyverse

I am chemistry researcher, and working with data where a variable was changed to see an effect on an outcome, for instance increase in temperature to see the change in conversion (conversion data not shown). What I want to do, is define a function to get the 'stable' temperature regions in my data. Here is an example of the [data](https://www.dropbox.com/s/q2qeniqqikydxkd/my_data.csv?dl=0). I have been able to get some of the data as a stable region, using a defined function, based on `plyr::round_any()` and `lubridate::round_date()`.

```
library(tidyverse)

all_data <- read_csv("my_data.csv")

trimmed_data <- all_data %>%

  mutate(

    round_temperature = plyr::round_any(Temperature, 0.5),

    round_hours = lubridate::round_date(Date, "12 hour")

  ) %>%

  group_by(round_temperature, round_hours) %>%

  mutate(

    Stable_Lead = if_else(

      round_temperature == lead(round_temperature, 1),

      TRUE, FALSE

    ),

    Stable_Lag  = if_else(

      round_temperature == lag(round_temperature, 1),

      TRUE, FALSE

    ),

    Stable = Stable_Lead + Stable_Lag

  ) %>%

  filter(

    Stable > 0

  ) %>%

  ungroup %>%

  select(-round_temperature, -contains("Stable"), -round_hours)
```

This is all going to plan, well sort of, and remove some of the unwanted increases or decreases in the data. What I want to do next, is to summarise this, or later to model this with a linear function.

My question now is, how do I use `group_by()` to group the whole 'stable' region? In the example, I would like to have the whole time region, between about 130 to 438 hours, to be one of the stable regions. Even in my version, this is not the case, and I would have like to have such a stable region define. In this case, it seems that there were 4 'stable' regions.

This is the ['stable' data](https://www.dropbox.com/s/jg4rxs932grhdge/my_data_trimmed2.csv?dl=0) done by hand.

Comment: How are you defining stable region? Are you using arbitrary hour ranges such as 130 to 438 hours or are these based on something else?

Comment: @Stedy, when I started with the data, there are periods of change, which I then remove via the code above. I then end with the final data. It is this data, that I want to summarise. The 130 to 438 hours was based on the first range, which all are within 0.5 °C of the mean, for that range. The next one is higher, since there was an increase, and is stable, until the next one, where the temperature was reduced, and so forth. However, as the third and first temperatures are very similar, these needs to be defined as two different regions, not one, thus another 'complication', so to speak.